# Issue with calculating years in CS50 llama lab

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int pop_start;
    int pop_end;
    int year = 0;
    int pop_val = 0;

    do
    {
        pop_start = get_int("Population start size: ");
    }
    while (pop_start < 9);
    // Prompt for end size
    do
    {
        pop_end = get_int("Population end size: ");
    }
    while (pop_end < pop_start);
    //calculate

    while (pop_end < pop_val)
    ;
    {
        pop_val = pop_val + (pop_val / 3) - (pop_val / 4);
        year++;
    }

    printf("years:%i\n", year);

}
```

I expected this program to work as intended and output the year value in accordance with the calculation. However regardless of the input values (pop_start) and (pop_end) the output value (year) is always 1 when it should be a higher number. I feel like i have to be missing something here but i am not quite sure what it is.

Comment: Hint: what's the value of `pop_val` when you first enter the `while` loop?

Comment: Remove the ; after the last while statement

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I expected this program to work as intended and output the year value in accordance with the calculation" This *doesn't tell us anything*; of course you expected the code to do what you wanted it to do, or you wouldn't have written it. What we need to know is *specifically what you thought the result should be*.

Comment: Anyway, this is a simple typo. Please look carefully at the code `while (pop_end < pop_val)`. What is on the next line? Do you see the `;` there? What effect do you expect this to have, and why? Aside from that, think carefully about the logic. When the `while` loop is reached, what value do you expect `pop_val` to have? Therefore, could the loop be entered? Where should the value of `pop_val` come from? For example, did you want to run the loop *always at least once*? (In this case - pay attention to the previous code, wherein you have already shown how to do this - twice!)

Comment: Finally, think carefully about the logic in `pop_val = pop_val + (pop_val / 3) - (pop_val / 4);`. What do you think should be the value of `pop_val`, the first time that this point in the code is reached? (Hint: after the `pop_val = 0` near the top of the code, is there anything else before now, that could change the value of `pop_val`?) If `pop_val` is `0` when this code is tried, what will it be afterwards? Do you see why this would cause a problem? What value should be used to start off instead?

Comment: Finally: please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum** and that we do not offer a [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) service. I am already offering you much more than I am supposed to with these hints. You are supposed to develop, for yourself, the skill of checking what the code does, carefully, step by step, and comparing it to your step-by-step expectation (and you should *have* one). We cannot teach this here.

Comment: Vimoxi, Note that `pop_val / 3` is integer division, no fraction in the result.  Is that intended?

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your code and found a couple of issues with your code that is tripping you up.  I did some refactoring whilst your issue was getting the above comments, but they also point to your basic issue with never initializing the "pop_val" variable to anything other than zero.  With that I offer up the following refactored code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int pop_start;
    int pop_end;
    int year = 0;
    int pop_val = 0;

    do
    {
        printf("Population start size: ");
        scanf("%d", &pop_start);
        //pop_start = get_int("Population start size: ");
    }
    while (pop_start < 9);

    pop_val = pop_start;    /* pop_val needs to be initialized to the starting size */
    // Prompt for end size
    do
    {
        //pop_end = get_int("Population end size: ");
        printf("Population end size: ");
        scanf("%d", &pop_end);
    }
    while (pop_end < pop_start);
    //calculate

    while (pop_end > pop_val)   /* Comparison needs to use ">" in lieu of "<" */
    {
        printf("pop_val: %d\n", pop_val);
        pop_val = pop_val + (pop_val / 3) - (pop_val / 4);
        year++;
    }

    printf("Years:%i\n", year);

    return 0;

}
```

Some bits of interest to point out.

- First off, I don't have the cs50.h file and library on my system, so I substituted standard combinations of "printf" and "scanf" statements to receive user input - you can change that back to the "get_int" functions for your code if needed.
- Next, the "pop_val" variable needed to be initialized to the starting value received in the "pop_start" variable.
- Right after your last "while" statement there is an extraneous semicolon, so that was removed (don't know if that was just a typo).
- Finally, the comparison operator in the last "while" statement is changed from ">" to "<"; otherwise, the program just drops out of the loop.

With those changes, following was a test run with the following terminal output.

```
@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Year/bin/Release$ ./Year 
Population start size: 1000
Population end size: 10000
pop_val: 1000
pop_val: 1083
pop_val: 1174
pop_val: 1272
pop_val: 1378
pop_val: 1493
pop_val: 1617
pop_val: 1752
pop_val: 1898
pop_val: 2056
pop_val: 2227
pop_val: 2413
pop_val: 2614
pop_val: 2832
pop_val: 3068
pop_val: 3323
pop_val: 3600
pop_val: 3900
pop_val: 4225
pop_val: 4577
pop_val: 4958
pop_val: 5371
pop_val: 5819
pop_val: 6304
pop_val: 6829
pop_val: 7398
pop_val: 8015
pop_val: 8683
pop_val: 9407
Years:29
```

Give those refactored code changes a try and see if it meets the spirit of your project.